# NewProxyCallableStatement cannot be cast to SQLServerCallableStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, c3p0

I have a generic API which accepts a connection. It would seem that one of the callers passes a connection, the `prepareCall` of which returns an object of type `NewProxyCallableStatement`. The following code then fails:

```
SQLServerCallableStatement stmt = (SQLServerCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall(sprocSQL);
```

The full exception seen by the caller of the API is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyCallableStatement cannot be cast to com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement
```

I need to use `SQLServerCallableStatement` because I am calling a stored procedure with an input argument of type `TABLE` and `SQLServerCallableStatement` has a `setStructured` method which allows constructing table type variables.

Comment: You can't cast because this is a logical statement from your connection pool that wraps the physical statement of the driver. Have you tried using `Statement.unwrap(..)` instead of trying to cast? You also may need to set certain connection pool properties to allow it to unwrap.

Comment: Bug in c3p0: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270883/c3p0-0-9-5-2-statement-unwrap-cause-abstractmethoderror

Comment: According to the 3 year old answer there, it was already fixed. If you can't use `unwrap`, then you are using an older version of c3p0.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I'm just adding it for future readers. It seems to have been fixed and if one updates their c3p0 version `unwrap` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the code below:

```
SQLServerCallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall(sprocSQL).unwrap(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.class);
```

If you are using c3p0, you'll need to use a version with the `unwrap` bug fixed. I tested the above with `c3p0-0.9.5.2`.

Reference:
[unwrap Method (SQLServerCallableStatement)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/unwrap-method-sqlservercallablestatement?view=sql-server-2017)